# Update data to my database with buttonclick

Tags: php

This is my first button. It loads my database

```
<input id="focusedInput" type="text" name="prodgr" value="">    
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Search">
</button>


$prodval= $_GET["prodgr"];        <-------
//Establish connection to database
$host = "*********";
$conn = db2_connect ($host,"*****", "*********");
$query = " Select * 
from p510F 
where p510key = '$prodval' ";
```

This is my second button. I want it to replace whats in my p510INF with the new value i write in my input field

```
<input id='focusedInput' type='text' name='submit' value=''>    
<button type='submit' class='btn btn-default' value='Change information 'text'>
</button>



if(isset($_POST['submit']))
$information= $_POST["submit"];  
{

     $SQL  = "UPDATE P510F (P510INF) VALUES ('information')
            where P510key = 'key'";
     $result = mysql_query($SQL);

}
```

$key is a  value where i stored my p510key.
Any suggestion what i missed for my code to work?

Comment: That's `UPDATE` you're trying to do by the way, not `INSERT`.

Comment: thank you, now i can google more about it